# Is there a way to turn an installed Python package into a zip or wheel file?

Tags: python, pip

There are some very old custom packages in my project, which do not exist in PyPI or other repositories. I need to migrate the `venv/` folder every time I deploy this project.

So is there a way to turn installed Python packages into zip or wheel files?

`zip file` means I can install the package via `pip instlal same_package.tar.gz`

Comment: I might be missing something here. You can turn Python packages into zip files by telling your favourite archiving application to turn them into zip files.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi zip file is a `Python Package`, not just a zip file

Answer (score 1):

So basically what you need to do is:

- Get the path of the virtualenv's site-packages by excuting the following command:

Code snippet

```
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib())
```

Now extract all wheel files form the wheels directory by

```
wheels = {os.path.basename(w).split('-')[0]: w for w in glob.glob("wheels/*.whl")}
```

First add all the site-packages without any package which is also available as a wheel into the zip file and then extract all the wheel files into a folder and add that folder as well into the final zip.

I found a python implementation in this [venv_bundler.py](https://gist.github.com/ovuruska/13e5af54cfb9c9cced57bb9c02acb1a0) gist.

Please feel free to try out.

Comment: I guess you might want to take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info. Basically, an answer should use links as *additional* information and still work without the linked content.

Comment: Cool.. i will update the answer with the additional information. Thanks.

Comment: This is better than compressing the venv/ folder. But I want to turn an installed package into a `package` that can be installed with `pip install`

Answer (score -2):

In each package directory run

```
python setup.py sdist
```

which will create a package file very like the ones uploaded on PyPI but in the local directory. Those can be installed with `pip install package.tar.gz`.

This and more is documented here: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/index.html. This is python3 but it should work just the same on 2.

Comment: `python setup.py sdist` requires `setup.py` and there are no one in **installed Python packages**.